# Pandas, create and combine rows into my desired columns

Tags: pandas, csv, split

I have the following csv file with just 1 column and more rows (I'm just adding 2 rows for simplicity)

```
|                  order_detail
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|product 1 & product 2|category 1|8~product 4|category 3 |10~product 1 & product 19|category 8|6~product 50|category 4|6
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|product 2|category 10|2~product 14|category 3 |1
```

I would like to create 3 columns off of that, so that my final output looks like this

```
productname           |category   |number of products
----------------------------------------------------
product 1 & product 2 |category 1 |8
product 4             |category 3 |10
product 1 & product 19|category 8 |6
product 50            |category 4 |6
product 2             |category 10|2
product 14            |category 3 |1
```

I have tried replacing the ~ character for | and then splitting the string but I can't get my desired output.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('./test.csv', encoding='ISO-8859–1', sep=',')

replacedString = df['ORDER_DETAIL'].str.replace('~', '|')

df[['productname','category','number of products']]= replacedString.str.split('|',2, expand=True)
```

I get the product and category in the correct format but the "number of products" is not creating other rows.

```
productname            |category   |number of products|
---------------------------------------------------------
Product 1 & product 2  |category 1 |8|product 4 | category 3 |10|product 1 & product 19|category 8|6|product 50|category 4|6
----------------------------------------------------------
product 2              |category 10|2|product 14|category 3|1
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: Can you add more code, so that the issue can be recreated?

Comment: Not sure if what I've added helps, but that's the only code I have, I have also added some screenshots of the csv file I'm working with.

Comment: I can't run the code locally, which makes it hard to provide a fix

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time asking here, am I able to upload the csv file or what else can I provide?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Take a look of: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You could add a sample of the head of the csv.

Comment: Thank you @MrNobody33, I have formatted the code already.